# mkfs a new device can not find the hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, filesystems

on `ubuntu`, I did an `lsblk`, and got

```
xvdb    202:16   0  100G  0 disk
```

this is the new disk I just mounted on a running ec2 instance. But when I do

```
mkfs xvdb
```

it says,

```
The file xvdb does not exist and no size was specified
```

when I do `df -h`, the new disk drive does not show at all.

What should I do to mount this new disk?

Answer (score 0):

need to add /dev/ in front of the name shown by lsblk.